# How to build a Jira-like SaaS site?

Tags: web-applications, architecture, saas

Anyone know how to build a single-tenant SaaS application like Jira, Wordpress.com, etc.. where every customer gets a separate site, but hosted on the company servers?

In the web seems to be a lot of information about multi-tenant SaaS applications and how to host them in sites like Heroku, Openshift, etc... but no much is said about single-tenant applications.

I've been reading a lot but I need that someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have got enough information about multi-tenant SaaS applications.
The single-tenant SaaS application referred to in the question is also termed hosting in the cloud. 
Usually the underlying implementation of the site is the same as multitenant SaaS, ie., those seperate sites could be served by a multitenant SaaS application. Or they could be separate deployments in the cloud.

Most of what you are asking is achieved using the wildcard subdomain names in the dns. Check with your devops if you dont have information about the dns records for your domain and how to set up a subdomain. A load balancer is usually used in combination. Here are some useful links

http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html