# How to assign a sub-domain to each user but still serve them from the same code instance?

Tags: session, dns, saas

How do sites like Wordpress.com assign a unique sub-domain to each user but still, I assume, support them all on the same instance?  What is the process of automatically managing the DNS entries?  Is there an advantage to supporting different users under their own sub-domain (e.g. client1.service.com) versus a separate path (e.g. service.com/client1)?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728119/how-to-build-a-jira-like-saas-site/25816652#25816652

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done through a combination of [DNS wildcards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) and [dynamically auto-configuring](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html) web server setups.  This means no continuing DNS (or web site) configuration is necessary as all possible hostnames +server instances automatically exist.

Having users under their same domain can help with isolating data (instead of having all users' data on a single hostname, each hostname has only a single user's data) and make the web site seems more personalized.

Comment: In what way does a unique sub-domain help isolate user data?

Comment: For the shared hostname, you'll have service.com/client1, service.com/client2 etc.  A user has to be very careful about always using their clientX prefix, if they do not add that they could direct their users to another client's account.  Similarly, if they include a link to the root they will be directing people to service.com/ and off their sub-site.  These possibilities are eliminated when you use a subdomain based scheme, as there is no prefix that's necessary to add.